# Rudin 9.6 Norm times modules of vector is greater than modulus of transformed vector

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, analysis

> (c) For $A \in L\left(R^{n}, R^{m}\right)$, define the norm $\|A\|$ of
> $A$ to be the sup of all numbers $|A \mathbf{x}|$, where $\mathbf{x}$
> ranges over all vectors in $R^{n}$ with $|\mathbf{x}| \leq 1$. Observe
> that the inequality $$ |A \mathbf{x}| \leq\|A\||\mathbf{x}| $$ holds
> for all $\mathbf{x} \in R^{n}$. Also, if $\lambda$ is such that $|A
> > \mathbf{x}| \leq \lambda|\mathbf{x}|$ for all $\mathbf{x} \in R^{n}$,
> then $\|A\| \leq \lambda$.

I am wondering why the above proposition  holds $$ |A \mathbf{x}| \leq\|A\||\mathbf{x}| $$

Does this follow directly from the definition of supremum?

Comment: Basically yes. You have to rewrite $x$ on the left-hand side as $|x| (x/|x|)$ so that you can satisfy the condition $|(x/|x|)| \le 1$ in order to use the supremum.

Comment: @angryavian is it trivial when x is zero?

Comment: @Sam Here $A$ is linear so $A0=0$, and $|0|=0$.  That is, when $x=0$, the inequality is just $0 \leq 0$. (note I do have three different "zeros" here, but the $0 \leq 0$ is your typical inequality of reals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from long time ago, but.

$|Ax|=|A|x|\frac{x}{|x|}|=|A\frac{x}{|x|}||x|$. Note that $\frac{x}{|x|}\leq 1\:\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$.

$||A|| := \sup_{x:|x|\leq 1} |Ax| = |A|$ because we would want $x$ such that $|x|=1$ for the supremum.

Then, $|A\frac{x}{|x|}|\leq |A|$. Finally,
$$|Ax|=|A\frac{x}{|x|}||x|\leq |A||x|=||A|||x|$$

This is summarized as $|Ax|\leq ||A|||x|$.

QED